# Cucumber scenario - correct scenario

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to improve my cucumber scenarios (BDD)

Lets say we have website, that can be in 3 states, and based on this state, it has different web elements in the page.

How would you write cucumber scenario making it as close to BDD methodologies, as simple to understand?

Currently I have:

```
  Scenario Outline: View page in <PAGE STATE> state
    Given I opened page in <PAGE STATE> state
    Then I should see "<AVAILABLE ELEMENTS>
    Examples:
      | PAGE STATE | AVAILABLE ELEMENTS                                         |
      | State1     | Value input, Default slider, Active slider,                |
      | State2     | Value input, Default slider, Active slider, Type dropdown  |
      | State3     | Value input, Default slider, Active slider, Image uploader |
```

Comment: Change the column name to `fields` and your step should be `Then I should see "<fields>" fields`. Update the step def accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend a scenario outline for all page states. You want each scenario to focus tightly on the thing you are asserting. For instance, the image uploader should be its own scenario:

```
Scenario: Users can upload an image when things are foobarred
    # One or more `Given` steps to put the system into the correct state
    Given a foo exists
    And bar has happened
    And a baz has been foobarred
    When I am viewing the page
    Then I should be able to upload an image
```

And a sample step making the assertion:

```cs
[Then(@"I (should|should not) be able to upload an image")]
public void ThenIShouldBeAbleToUploadAnImage(string assertion)
{
    bool isFound = false;

    try
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.Css("input[type='file']"));

        isFound = true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    if (assertion == "should")
    {
        // Assert isFound is true
    }
    else
    {
        // Assert isFound is false
    }
}
```

The scenario name clearly states a narrow test case. Each state of the page is clearly defined in the `Given` steps for this scenario. It also has only one assertion, and therefore only one reason this scenario should ever fail (the image upload field is not present).

You want your scenarios to focus on a single behavior. Your steps should not be describing the technical details of a page or screen, and instead should describe what the user is doing. You shouldn't assert that the upload field is visible. You should assert you are *able to upload an image* and have the step definition take care of finding the image upload field.

See [BDD 101: Writing Good Gherkin](https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/30/bdd-101-writing-good-gherkin/) for more advice on how to write good steps that describe behavior rather than a step by step process to accomplish a task.

Comment: Thank you for valuable input, that helps a lot. Outside of this conversation, so conclusion would be that cucumber is not good for this sort of tests where we need to check that say page has its all web elements, with cucumber we focus on behaviours that is clear now. How would you recommend to deal with both types of tests? Regards

Comment: @Matthewek: You can still write those kinds of tests in cucumber, however I would shy away from steps like `I should not see the "X" field` - steps whose terminology is more technically focused or user interfaced based. Try to word the steps to capture the business use case or business process. And even then, temper that with pragmatism. Sometimes you just need to know the silly element is on screen.